# fetching a different query from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

So I have a database of artists and they all show by default, if I click photographers they become hidden and only the photographers load after that, same for the makeup artists.

I'm achieving this by creating 3 php pages for fetching each with a different sql query--is there a way to do that without having 3 separate pages?

Because when I want to update the fetch page I need to update 3 of them now.

```
//click to load ph/mk
$( "#ph" ).click(function() {
  $(".feed_item").hide();
  fetch = 'fetch_ph.php';
  load_contents(1);
  });
$( "#mk" ).click(function() {
  $(".feed_item").hide();
  fetch = 'fetch_mk.php';
  load_contents(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way (in my opinion) to achieve this is by putting all three functions into one PHP file and calling the actual method by sending a trigger to activate that function and return the information.

So make three functions (fetch_ph(), fetch_mk(), fetch_artists()) and then use a trigger word to get one of the functions to call.

So from my understanding of your question, this would be the best thing to do.

```
<?php

 $triggerword = $_POST['triggerword'];

 if ($triggerword === "mk")
     {
     fetch_mk();
     } 
     else if ($triggerword === "ph")
     {
     fetch_ph();
     } 
     else if ($triggerword === "artists")
     {
     fetch_artists();
     }

 function fetch_artists()
     {
     //function to get artists here...
     }

 function fetch_mk()
     {
     //function to fetch makeup artists...
     }

 function fetch_ph()
     {
     //function to fetch photographers...
     }

?>
```